# Is there a generic CIL code to convert any type instance to string?

Tags: .net, cil, il, mono.cecil

Is it possible to write generic CIL instructions which will convert instances of any type (both value and reference) to System.String?
In particular, I'm interested in Mono.Cecil code which will inject those instructions into a method.

Analyzing a generic method I came up with these Mono.Cecil calls:
(it's supposed to convert the i-th method parameter to string)

```
System.Reflection.MethodInfo to_string_method_info = typeof( System.Object ).GetMethod( "ToString" );
Mono.Cecil.MethodReference to_string_reference = injectible_assembly.MainModule.Import( to_string_method_info );

Mono.Cecil.TypeReference argument_type = method_definition.Parameters[ i ].ParameterType;
method_definition.Body.Instructions.Add( processor.Create( Mono.Cecil.Cil.OpCodes.Constrained, argument_type ) );
method_definition.Body.Instructions.Add( processor.Create( Mono.Cecil.Cil.OpCodes.Callvirt, to_string_reference ) );
```

However, when debugging I get an exception from the injected method that the "JIT compiler encountered internal limitation".

Comment: In cases like this, PEVerify can be very useful, because it can tell you what specific error your code has.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Edit:

Also important: note that I am using `typeof(object).GetMethod(...)`, not `typeof(T).GetMethod(...)` - your line `argument_type.GetType().GetMethod( "ToString" );` looks very suspect IMO.

---

I suspect the issue is that you are loading a local/argument, rather than the **address** of a local/argument - in the line *immediately before* what is shown. `Constrained` needs this so that it can correctly perform the static-call implementation; for the virtual-call implementation, it can simply dereference this to get the *actual* reference.

Other than that: `Constrained` should work fine - see below (in particular, note the `Ldarga_S`). Of course, another option is to use `Box`, but this will have more overhead. `Constrained` is the *ideal* way of calling `ToString` on an arbitrary type.

```
using System;
using System.Reflection.Emit;

public class RefTypeNoImpl { }
public class RefTypeImpl { public override string ToString() { return "foo"; } }
public struct ValTypeNoImpl { }
public struct ValTypeImpl { public override string ToString() { return "bar"; } }

static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Test<RefTypeNoImpl>();
        Test<RefTypeImpl>();
        Test<ValTypeNoImpl>();
        Test<ValTypeImpl>();
    }


    static void Test<T>() where T : new()
    {
        var dm = new DynamicMethod("foo", typeof(string), new[] { typeof(T) });
        var il = dm.GetILGenerator();
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarga_S, 0);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Constrained, typeof(T));
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, typeof(object).GetMethod("ToString"));
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
        var method = (Func<T, string>)dm.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<T, string>));
        Console.WriteLine(method(new T()));
    }
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was doing: Ldarg instead of Ldarga.

Comment: @zagrobelski not a bad guess ;p